# “I can't be available” vs “I will not be available”

Tags: modal-verbs, future, defective-verbs

I had written “I can't be available from 9-10.” My friends suggested that I rewrite it as “I can't be available from 9-10”. Both answers were not satisfying me. I had searched on the internet for correct form sentence. The suggestion is I need to use the verb will rather than can.

> 1. I can't be available from 9-10.
> 2. I can't available from 9-10.
> 3. I will not be available from 9-10.

Can anyone explain me in detail difference in three statements? How *be* effected tense of statement 1 & 2?  Where can I use *can* in the future sentence with detailed examples?

Comment: Please see also [ell.se] Good Luck.

Comment: The colloquial expression is 'I am not available ...'. 'Cannot' is not really true. I can if I want, but I choose not to be and therefore I am not.

Comment: The first two examples are identical. Who wrote 1 and who 2?

Comment: Ahh there's an answer, I didn't see that in the review queue. Regardless, the formatting had to be improved on, and I fixed minor grammar details.

Comment: @Mari-LouA First one was by me, the second one was from my friend.

Comment: I was referring to the first two examples in the opening paragraph. They are identical *“I can't be available from 9-10.” My friends suggested that I rewrite it as “I can't be available from 9-10”* Both sentences are the same. The ones listed 1-3 are different.

Comment: @Mari-LouA, In the second sentence I didn't use the word `be`.

Comment: In the introduction paragraph, not the ones listed in the box, the two sentences both have "be". (“I can't **be** available from 9-10.” My friends suggested that I rewrite it as “I can't **be** available from 9-10”) I mean, it's not important now but it confused me at the time.

Comment: @Mari-LouA , Sorry, at that time I didn't pay attention to that point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell what you wrote and what your friends suggested are exactly the same so I can't comment on that, but here are some thoughts on the three numbered sentences:

1. This is grammatically correct, but is semantically odd as `available` isn't generally volitional (although some people use it that way)--it describes a state of being and not an action.
2. This is not grammatically correct; `available` is an adjective and can't be used as a verbal complement to `can't`.
3. This is also grammatically correct and is preferred over `1` because `will` can be used in a non-volitional sense as in "I will be alive tomorrow."

Alternatively, you can also dispense with the modal verb `will` and just say, "I am not available from 9 to 10 (am? pm?)" or "I am unavailable from 9 to 10 (am? pm?)"

Also, as a side note, `suggest` can't take an indirect object ("suggested me to"). Some acceptable ways to use it would be:

1. My friends suggested (that) I do this
2. My friends suggested doing this.
3. My friends suggested this sentence.
4. My friends suggested what I should write.

See this for more information:
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/common-verbs/suggest

Comment: *unavailable (typo, last sentence?). Also, in 2 in the original question, "attend" would substitute nicely for "available".

Comment: @ZacharyLim `You suggested me, right?` Is it a correct sentence and usage for suggest?

Comment: @kvk30 No, `me` is an indirect object. Take a look at the link I included.

Comment: Then it would be rewritten as `my friends suggested to me`, right?

Comment: `to me` is just a prepositional phrase; you still need a direct object, e.g. `My friends suggested to me that I eat an apple.` While many languages allow the direct object to be left out, English doesn't.

Comment: Sorry, from the review queue I inadvertently fixed the grammar of "suggest" not knowing that a user had posted an answer. I fixed it because it was divorced from the question, which was about can + be + available.

Comment: If you are also providing a reason for your unavailability (e.g. being out of the country) then "can't be available" might be appropriate. It has connotations (to me) that you would _like_ to be there but circumstances prevent it.